# How to turn bitmaps into a video with arbitrary framerate?

Tags: opengl, video, bitmap, avi

I've got an OpengGL based rendering engine that I use for some scientific visualization and I capture .bmps from the frames.  I was looking for something to write them into a video that allowed arbitrary framerates?  I found something (a windows API) to make vidoes with integer spacing in milliseconds between frames, but I wanted to make exactly 60fps videos.  I need to keep the frames uncompressed (or at least lossless compression), but I imagine uncompressed is easier.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Just another reason NTSC should be taken out and shot. 50 Hz is so much more elegant and would have made life so much simpler :-\

Comment: ffmpeg/libavcodec or the libav fork are able to do what you want. Are you asking for a specific API or do you need just a tool for the task?

Comment: I suppose either would work, but an API would be preferred, I think.  I'll take a look into the two you mentioned.